# Datastore on Google Cloud Platform Oauth2 error and Data disappearing

Tags: oauth-2.0, datastore

I have recently lost all access to Google Cloud Platform Datastore for my app.  I have records missing completely from my app and when I tried to check the data through the google cloud platform console I can no longer see any data or indexes.
I receive the following error when I try to view entities (no entities show up in the list anymore and this error appears if I try to manually enter a value in the kind field)
"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project%22)
When I try to view indexes I receive a "Failed to load" error.
I have lost access to my database completely and I'm uncertain where to go from here.  The app I'm using if for our CMS for our homeless charity which includes rental and tenancy information, sales information from our op shop and foodbank, and lots of client information regarding homelessness, mental health, counselling and addiction records.
Some of my clients have completely disapppeared from our system.  I don't know how to save my data.  Please help.

UPDATE :  have been able to access datastore by updating google chrome, this has fixed the Oauth2 issue.  While I can now see the data, this hasn't fixed the issue of the missing records.  I'm currently migrating and updating my app from appengine ndb to cloud ndb and python 2 to python 3.  I'm hoping this prevents future losses, but i've lost faith in the integrity of google datastore.

Comment: Same exact problem here. Using an up-to-date version of Chrome does not help. It worked for a while with Firefox, so I doubt it's browser-dependant.